# Why my image tag wont work in ruby on rails in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am currently doing a CRUD with image.. Am encountering error "ExecJS::ProgramError in Products#index TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method" when I displaying the image in my view

Question: How should I display my image in my view? Why is that?

NOTE: My friend didn't install anything like imagemagik & paperclip.. I also tried to display a static image in my view(assets/images folder) and its not working

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MY STORE!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><align="center"> WELCOME TO MY STORE</h1>
    <%= link_to 'Add Product', new_product_path %>
    <table border = "1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Image</td>

            <td>Size</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Created At</td>
            <td>Updated At</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <% @product.each do |p| %>

        <tr>
            <td><%= p.id %></td>
            <td><%= p.name %></td>

            <td><%= image_tag p.image %></td>
            <td><%= p.size %></td>
            <td><%= p.price %></td>
            <td><%= p.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></td>
            <td><%= p.updated_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></td>
            <td>
            <%= link_to 'View', product_path(p) %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(p) %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Schema**

```
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20170406144121) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "carts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "size"
    t.float    "price"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "image"
  end

  create_table "user", id: :integer, default: -> { "nextval('customers_id_seq'::regclass)" }, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "full_name"
    t.string   "product_name"
    t.string   "size"
    t.float    "price"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_foreign_key "carts", "products"
end
```

Comment: Post an exact error message please.

Comment: what is type of that image `attribute`? does it return image itself, or path(link) string of it?

Comment: @marmeladze the attribute/type of my image column is string(in pgAdmin equivalent is character varying).. I also tried to use the AT(symbol) product.inspect, all the data is there

Comment: Are you sure all your products have images ? If not it would break.

Comment: Give an example of a value of p.image, and the path of this image from rails root.

Comment: If `p.image` doesn't print a full path of an image that won't be a valid `src` attribute for an `img` tag, see what's currently printing.

Comment: @AlexanderLuna Yes, all my data's have images

Comment: @VasilyYudin I put in my pgAdmin is just the file name with the extension(example dp.jpg) like that

Comment: That won't do. For the image tag to work you need more than the file name. You will either need a path to the file on your local files system or the link to the file where you are storing it. Or else Rails doesn't know where to pick the image from.

Comment: Something must have been different else you wouldn't have a problem. Show your schema file and an example product if possible.

Comment: For the example, id,name,size,price, created_at, updated_at, image values 4 Product 1, Small, 700, 2017-04-07, 2017-04-07, dp.jpeg I also updated my post, i already put my schema file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is commonly related to a CoffeeScript compatibility issue with Windows. Downgrading the gem should solve it.

Locate your coffee-script-gem and change it for the following:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

Then run:

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

*Please check where the error points to (file and line) if this solution doesn't work, and update your question.

Comment: Sir, are you talking about is go to the gemfile then add the gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' to adjust the version of my coffee then bundle update it?

Comment: I'm not a "Sir", but yes, that's what I mean :) try it. There are a couple of other things you can do, but start from there.

Comment: Wups, sorry my bad.. I created another forum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43314458/rails-5-execjsprogramerror-in-collectionstesting can you check it?

Comment: Did you restart the server after downgrading the gem? If still doesn't work, try to removing this line " //= require_tree " from application.js and revert the change you've done of changing application to default, this will give you errors finding other files. This will cause an error finding files in your app (as you've encountered).

Comment: I already resolved my problem.. I updated my version my rails into 5.0+(my latest of rails is just 2.3) i think thats the reason why its not working

Comment: can you elaborate more your solution for future people with the same issue? which version of coffee script did you end up using? Did you have to change something else?

Comment: I posted an answer