# Rails - 5 ExecJS::ProgramError in Collections#testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I created a new project with name of the controller collections(install the rails 2.3 then update it to 5.1 version, gem install bundler, bundle install, ruby 2.33 ).. I tried to run the collections/index I am getting this error on windows. I do some research regarding to this error, followed all the instructions given

Putting the gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0' into my gem file then bundle update coffee-script-source. I also change the application into default(located at application.html.erb) but when I change it to default it gives me another error "Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Collections#testing The asset "default.css" is not present in the asset pipeline."

Question: What should I do to fix this error?

Comment: which version of Windows do you have?

Comment: The version of my windows is 7

Comment: you shouldn't change the line into default (located at application.html.erb). This will cause an error finding files in your app (as you've encountered). Make sure you restart the server after downgrading gem. Also, update/edit your original question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248409/why-my-image-tag-wont-work-in-ruby-on-rails-in-windows/ . This is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why my image tag wont work in ruby on rails in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248409/why-my-image-tag-wont-work-in-ruby-on-rails-in-windows)